# href="javascript:" open in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website where the developer used href="javascript" for the links. I need the links to open in a new tab when the user clicks on them but when I make the target equal to _blank or the base equal to _blank a new tab opens but nothing is on the page. The links themselves go to an external site.

Can someone explain to me why this is and how I could possibly get the links working properly?

Example of one of the links:

```
<a href="javascript:SubmitPurchaseLink('Ticks1545037499', '%7eYn%7eJva2%7eVya%7eW%7eQ9%7eM%7eTc2%7eM%7eS%7eZza%7eX%7eRlbn%7eVt%7eYm%7eVy%7eP%7eT%7eE4%7eJn%7eRna%7eW%7eQ9%7eM%7eT%7eU0%7eN%7eT%7eAz%7eNz%7eQ5%7eO%7eS%7eZldn%7eRp%7eZ%7eD0y%7eN%7eD%7eIy%7eMz%7eA4%7eJn%7eBya%7eW%7eNl%7eP%7eT%7eEy%7eN%7eS4w%7eM%7eD%7eAw%7eJm%7eN1cn%7eJlbm%7eN5a%7eW%7eQ9%7eM%7eQ..!%7eB2pn%7eE%7eJ%7eIv%7eSts.')">
```

Comment: They're not really "links" - the developer misused the "href" attribute to cause clicks on the element to run some JavaScript code, and it's the code that's doing the real work. You'll have to fix the code itself; you can't remedy the situation by changing the HTML.

Comment: You will need to modify the `SubmitPurchaseLink` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the `SubmitPurchaseLink` function and within that function need to open target URL to a new tab.

```
function SubmitPurchaseLink() {
  // your code

  // code to open URL to a new window
  window.open(url, '_blank');   
}
```

Ref: [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.open)